# HTML inline style color

Tags: html, css, meteor

This Meteor server code composes the html to be inserted in mongodb which supplies the documents to the template helper for displaying.

The image below shows the browser element, but the word "Free" is not green as I expected it.  Any idea how to make it green? thx

`const free = '<span style="color:green">Free</span>';`

[image]

Comment: Although the JavaScript placement of the Element may appear to work, I don't believe `<option>`s support CSS and inline style for `.innerHTML` on some Browsers. Make the dropdown another way to style it like that. In short `<option>` must not have other Elements within it.

Comment: You're better off using an HTML replacement for your <select> if you want to do this.

Comment: The World needs to know that `<option>` and `<button>` both do not support Elements within them on many a Browser.

Comment: Didn't read your question well enough the first time. Yeah you can't put a tag in an `option` and styling `select` lists is very limited and different browsers support different levels of customization. There are lots of plugins that you can use that will convert your select element into html/css that you can customize/style to your heart's content. select2 is a good one https://select2.github.io/